# How can I join values of Point features to raster dataset in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, raster, raster-conversion

I have to join point values to rasters. Every points are located at the geometrical centre of the raster cells. Every single cells have to include the point values that are in their centre. Unfortunately, spatial join works only with vector features. I used point raster tool and after that I used Mosaic to new raster tool because the rasters are not in the same layer. After the mosaic the new raster, I am not able to join because there are multiple rasters with the same ID. I need exactly the opposite of what extract values to points tool does. Namely, I want to extract point values to raster. Does somebody know how can I do that?

Comment: Your work flow sounds correct to me, convert points to a raster them mosaic that with the other raster making sure mosaic method is LAST.

Comment: That's works. Thank you.